# cakephp auth allow to specific actions of specific controllers

Tags: cakephp, authentication, controller, action

I have admin authentication with the following beforeFilter() method in appController.php.
I am using cakePhp 2.4

```
public function beforeFilter() { 

        $this->Auth->allow(
                array(
                    'controller'=>
                    'Services','Projects','News','Jobs','Messages',
                    'action'=>
                    'index','view'
                    )
                );
}
```

I want to allow access to
  1- index action of all controllers
  2- view action of only Jobs controller
currently I have allowed access to index and view actions of all controllers.
how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this-> Auth-> allow(array('index'))` in appcontroller and`$this-> Auth-> allow(array('index', 'view'))` in JobsController.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a common problem to CakePHP developer to auth allow to specific actions of a specific controller. See this article to solve it.

https://blog.sohelrana.me/cakephp-auth-allow-specific-actions-specific-controllers/